How to perform overbooking testing in JMeter to simulate more booking requests than available resources?
I am currently working on load testing a booking system using JMeter and need to test how the system handles overbooking scenarios, where the number of booking requests exceeds the number of available resources.
I’m having trouble understanding how to correctly simulate and test these overbooking scenarios using JMeter.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Sounds like you just need to have at least as many threads (virtual users) in the Thread Group as the number of resources + 1 (or higher number)
If you want to fire booking events at exactly the same moment - add a Synchronizing Timer as a child of your request and set Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by to be equal to the number of threads in the Thread Group
You can also add a Response Assertion to check the content of the response and ensure that it contains anticipated text and/or doesn't contain errors
